# ui bootstrap modal and ui-view ui-router

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

ui-view content not load in ui bootstrap modal .
here my state from ui-router configuration :

```
.state('home.connexion', {
            url: '/connexion',
            views: {
                "maincontent@home": {
                    templateUrl: 'app/connexion/connexion.html'
                },
                "connectionModal@home.connexion": {
                    templateUrl: 'app/connexion/modal.html'
                },
                "registerTypeModal@home.connexion": {
                    templateUrl: 'app/register/modTypeRegister.html'
                },
                "registerModal@home.connexion": {
                    templateUrl: 'app/register/modRegister.html'
                },
                "cguStatement@home.connexion": {
                    templateUrl: 'app/cgu/statement.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

my nested view :

```
<div ui-view="cguStatement" autoscroll="false"></div>
```

when i put it inside page => OK

when i put it **inside  modal => KO**

I need help :)

Comment: My question isn't clear

Comment: Have I to add some explanations ????

Comment: No one can help me ???